# Can i replace 3 (parallel) capacitors 16v 1800uf with 16v 2200uf?

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics, computers, motherboard

[image]
The motherboard model is G31T-M REV:1.0 .
The circuit is for the 4-pin 12v power rail coming from the power supply.

I'm replacing these because they are very bloated,
It's quite a miracle that the capacitors are still working xD

Comment: I expect you can replace them but whether it works correctly afterwards is purely dependant on what the circuit is intended to do in the bigger picture.

Comment: https://www12.mediafire.com/convkey/ba53/31nngngckt1rk464g.jpg?session_token=1b902ce7131ac558cc9185e3bfb208077ca9915299c7613e27b4f64de91bc80629bb4c4498b8e3caa396756c56f2f15d1dd47fa870a1b13688de199e2aec154a999cebbb02432837

Comment: It would of course be better if you had the exact spec, but yolo, go for it.

Comment: Idk what to do 

Comment: Are you planning on using 1 x 2200 uF or 3 x 2200 uF?

Comment: I'll be replacing 3 x 1800uf with 3 x 2200uf (planning to)

Comment: Do you have the actual p/n of the two caps and  spec sheets?

Comment: I've replaced it and it works, thank you everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increasing capacitance within reasonable limits won't cause trouble in a power supply bypassing scenario, which is the case here.

If the caps are in a hot place, make sure you use 105°C rated caps, and not 85°C ones. Note that even at a much lower temp like 50°C, the higher rated cap will last longer.

These look like they're at the input side of the CPU VRM, which means they will handle high currents. Low-ESR caps are required in this position, try caps specified for switching power supplies for example.

Personally I would use [these](http://uk.farnell.com/panasonic-electronic-components/eeufr1c222/cap-alu-elec-2200uf-16v-rad/dp/1800641), they're cheap and high quality.

General-purpose aluminium electrolytic caps (the ones that aren't specified for low-ESR) are likely to have too much ESR to use here.

Also check this [link](https://badcaps.net/forum/showthread.php?t=13347), apparently you're not the only customer to have problems with this mobo...

Comment: The caps are 105°C and it's identical to the caps you mentioned

Comment: It's running a'lot better now and it worked like a charm. 

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, other than the physical size of the part being compatible with the board layout, a small percentage larger capacitance used in a circuit like yours should be OK.

Comment: The physical size of the capacitor is exact

Comment: No, especially for power caps the ESR and ESI is as important too, a lot of caps fail not because their value "shrinks" but because ESR or ESI are too high.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - A good thought in general, but the proposed replacement is only 20% greater than the original, and I'm dubious that this will cause a problem. So long as the replacement is otherwise in the same ballpark for use type (low ESR especially), of course.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: From the way the OP presents the question it is rather unlikely they pay any attention to that part, so one has to assume that they mean "just any with that value" for which the answer is "no, not just any, must be similar ESR/ESI too"

Comment: @PlasmaHH - Fair enough. "It's hard to make things foolproof..."